# Custom Extended Properties on AppointmentItem is not available for Recipients

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Before sending the appointmentItem in outlook 2010 I have created an extended property and set some values. The property is not available for the recipient (recipients are using outlook and they are from the same domain).

However, the property is available in the owner's calendar item.

Any inputs about this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that ApointmentItem object is never sent - Outlook creates a MeetingItem object and sends. The original ApointmentItem remains in the Calendar folder.

You can try to use Application.ItemSend event - Outlook will pass MeetingItem as the parameter, and you should be able to set the extra properties. Now where these properties will be copied by Outlook from MeetingItem in the Inbox to the new ApointmentItem is a different question...

Answer (score 0):

I have already replied to your post on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5797927c-b771-40c4-8502-87c346e8b22c/how-to-added-named-property-into-a-meeting-item?forum=outlookdev) two days ago:

> The fact is that a meeting item is not sent to a recipient. Instead, a corresponding meeting request is created and sent to the recipient. Just check the message class of the item when the item is sent. You can handle the ItemSend event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an  Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item.